# why "has been telling" and not "has told"?

Tags: perfect-constructions

good morning,can someone explain the difference in this sentence I came across recently:

> "The point of both is say that the writer has been telling the truth".

I found it on [this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11661/when-ending-an-email-should-i-use-yours-faithfully-or-best-regards) when arguing about "yours faithfully vs regards", I don't understand why not "has told"?

Comment: "The point of both is say that the writer": this is not correct grammatically; you should check the sentence. This use of "say" cannot be  "say" as meaning "for example", so it makes no sense.

Comment: What is the intended sense of the quote?

Comment: The writer of the comment presumably left out the word _to_. He could have said 'has told the truth', but it's perfectly idiomatic to use the continuous tense when speaking of a recently completed action which has taken some time (writing a letter).

Answer (score 0):

The sentence quoted contains an error: “to” has been omitted in front of “say.” And “both” refers to “yours faithfully” and “yours sincerely.” The phrase “regards” is not the topic of the quoted sentence, which means

> The point of both closings, yours faithfully” and “yours sincerely,” is to affirm that the writer has been telling the truth.

The progressive “has been telling” is appropriate because writing a letter is a process taking time. The progressive is not mandatory, but is certainly idiomatic.